# Why does this program tell me more than I want to know? I want it only to tell me once that it found the number or didn't

Tags: java, loops

Why does this program tell me more than I want to know? ("Not found," Not found," etc.) I want it only to tell me once that it found the number or didn't. I believe it has to do with the last loop. I was told: //you need to loop here, ranging i from 0 to numNum, searching in thisNum[i] for the number (for the last loop.)

```
// HighLow Program
public class numSearch2 //Program
{ // here is the main method of the program
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, numNums, outPut; //variables

        System.out.println("This program will allow you to enter some numbers.\nIt will then tell you the numbers you entered. \nThen you will be asked to enter any number and \nthe program will tell you where in the array the number is located. ");

        System.out.println("\nFirst, please enter how many numbers you will enter: "); //input the number of numbers
        numNums = InputUtils.GetInt(); //pulls from InputUtils program

        if (numNums > 0) //if statement
        {
            // dynamically declare (or 'new up') the array of int...
            int numArray[]; // variable
            numArray = new int[numNums];

            //loop x times
            for (i = 0; i < numNums; i++) {
                System.out.println("Please enter number " + i + ": "); // enter this number
                numArray[i] = InputUtils.GetInt();//pulls from InputUtils program
            }   // end if statement

            System.out.println("Here are the numbers you entered: "); //shows all the numbers entered

            for (i = 0; i < numNums; i++) {
                System.out.println("\n Number " + i + " is " + numArray[i]); //spits out numbers
            }

            System.out.println("\nWhat number would you like to search for: "); //find the number
            outPut = InputUtils.GetInt(); //pulls from InputUtils program

            for (i = 0; i < numNums; i++)//loop for the return numbers

                if (numArray[i] == outPut) //if the number you're looking for matches up with a number entered, this will tell you
                {
                    System.out.println("That number was found at location " + i); //tells you what number it matches with
                } else //if the number you're looking for doesn't match up:
                {
                    System.out.println("number not found"); //tells the user the number cannot be found
                }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        }


    }  // end main
}   // end class
```

Comment: This is what it tells me for every number that doesn't match the search: number not found
number not found
number not found
number not found

Comment: Look where that message is printed. It is in a loop (the only thing in that loop), so it is repeated for `numNums` times.

Comment: You can't know whether the number is not found until you've looked at all the numbers.  Therefore, the statement to print `not found` must happen after the loop is completed, not inside the loop.  If you put it inside the loop, of course it will print it multiple times--why isn't that obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the inner loop with:

```
boolean found = false;
for (i=0; i<numNums; i++)
    if (numArray[i]==outPut) {
        System.out.println("That number was found at location " +i );
        found = true;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("number not found");
}
```

You have to remembber wether or not you found any value and only after the entire iteration print that you did not find anything if that is the case.

Comment: Thank you!!! I really appreciate everyone's comments and help! especially you luk! I'm new to Java and it doesn't seem like my mind is grasping it yet.

Comment: @TravisDutton-Leyda if this answered your question, please click on the checkmark on its left to mark it as accepted.